# Мониторинг сообщений определенного пользователя в telegram Telebot python

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Хочу сделать так, что-бы бот отслеживал все сообщения в группе и если человек с определенным айдишником напишет в чат, то бот пересылает мне это сообщение.
Пересылку сделать могу, но вот отслеживание за конкретным пользователем допереть не могу как сделать ._.

Буду очень благодарен вам, если поможете)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: У вас получилось создать бота?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделай функцию, которая будет фильтровать сообщения по id, т.е. `message.from_user.id` , либо можешь сделать декоратор типа

```
    def id_check(f):
        def wrapper_id(message):
            if message.from_user.id == 'id пользователя':
                result = f(message)
                return result
        return wrapper_id
```

И продекорируй функцию, которая должна использовать этот id

```
@bot.channel_post_handler(func=lambda message: True)
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
@id_check
def get_message(message):
    pass
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).